# How do I break a loop of elements in intern

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intern

Let's say I have the following DOM structure

```
<table id="campaigns">
   <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>first data</td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-id="1">
      <td>intern test at Fri, 09 Dec 2016 03:12:26 GMT</td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-id="2">
      <td>intern test at Fri, 09 Dec 2016 03:12:26 GMT</td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-id="3">
      <td>intern test at Fri, 09 Dec 2016 03:12:26 GMT edit</td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-id="4">
      <td>another data</td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-id="5">
      <td>next data</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

and this is how i do it in intern

```
this.remote
     .findAllByXpath("//*[@id='campaigns']/tr"") //  get allitem from list
        .then(function (options) {
            return Promise.all(options.map(function (option) {
                return option.getVisibleText()
                    .then(function (text) {
                        if (text.includes("intern test")) {  //   checked whether the value is exist
                             option.click(); // click the value
                        }
                         return text;
                    })
            }))
         })
```

my requirement is only to click one the text that contain "**intern test**".
This code seems fine but what happens is that when intern already clicking the first element in the if statement, the next element seems will also perform the click and stale the element.
How do I stop this loop and proceed when it found the 1st element?

Thanks for any help provide

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you rephrase it? Are there several elements to be clicked or multiple?
`Promise.all` will wait until all promises are resolved, thus letting it run. If you want to only wait until *one* is resolved, have a look at `Promise.race()`.

Comment: thanks for the response. I only want to click the 1st element satisfy the if statement, not the 1st element it found. Promise.race will not satisfy the if statement since it will take the 1st element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to go through all the elements to find the first element containing text "intern test"

Try the following XPath using `findAllByXpath` (I am not aware of Javascript - selenium, so, please correct the syntax if required):

```
//table[@id='campaigns']/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'intern test')]/..
```

returns all the `tr` elements with text containing `intern test` inside the table with id `campaigns`.

Use indexing, like `0, 1, 2` to match `first, second and third` elements containing `intern test`

Comment: thanks for the response. But my requirement is to click **tr element** , not **td element** , the **xpath** that you have suggested will not help with that requirement

Comment: edited my answer. please try it out. just added "/.." to get the parent i.e., "tr"

Comment: Thanks.this help me. need to brush my skill on xpath